# Setting values in a time frame to zero

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, python-datetime

I have a `df` with `DateTimeIndex` (hourly readings) and light intensity.

```
Time                   Light
1/2/2017 18:00          31     
1/2/2017 19:00          -5     
1/2/2017 20:00          NA
......
......
2/2/2017 05:00          NA
2/2/2017 06:00          20
```

The issue is that after sunset (6 pm) until sunrise (6 am), the sensor doesn't work and has bad readings. I would like to set any readings in this period to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask with these conditions and set the value based on it.

```
hours = (df.index.to_series().dt.hour) # convert DateTimeIndex to hours
mask = (hours > 6)  & (hours < 18)
df.loc[~mask, 'Light'] = 0
```

You should convert the `DataTimeIndex` to `Series` to access the datetime methods.

Comment: Seems like you should invert the mask here

Comment: This worked after modifying to suit my condition:
mask = (hours < 6)  | (hours > 18)